# How to create Perth Metropolitan Area Map in SVG

Tags: svg, maps, geojson, shapefile, topojson

I am working on a project where Users can interact with a Map via mouse click to see more details of an area. It is [Perth Metropolitan Area Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj7pR.jpg). This Map is generated from PDF using online "PDF to SVG converter".

When I looked at generated SVG code it is so huge can't understand full of it. and did some research to see if i can find any simpler version of the Map, I see there are various options to construct SVG, detailed below.

- Shapefiles : Creating maps based on real world data, I thought this is good option to go. but the problem I observed here is we need to depend on GIS tools and open databases where GIS data is available. It is too heavy for our requirement.
- Geo JSON / Topo JSON : I see this is simple way to represent Maps in plain, but I could not figure out a way to generate required JSON files. After exploring more on this I understood these technologies are dependent on GIS / Shapefiles.
- Inscape : UI editor to draw SVG  - It is just generating lot of SVG code again.

After reviewing above all I kind of thinking may be I should learn to write own SVG map.

Can somebody advice whether I am in right direction or Are there any simple approaches to create a Map like this [Perth Metropolitan Area Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj7pR.jpg) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no reason why the SVG should be huge. Obviously the PDF to SVG converter is generating a lot of unnecessary content. Often this can be because of text formatting differences between PDF and SVG.  I suggest you post a small amount of the SVG so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @Paul, Thanks for reply. Here is svg code I am currently using http://ctademos.com/map.txt

Comment: That URL is 404ing.